# Override or set authenticated user in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I need to override the current authenticated user, e.g.

```
Joe Smith ABC fhjsdj342
```

to

```
fhjsdj342
```

As you can see, there's a fixed scheme (last token).

The new user id is needed for authorization.

I appreciate any hints or comments. But here are some more concrete questions:

1. Is the authenticated user stored in any way usable in the config? I know, for logging it can received by %u. Then, there's the Apache variable REMOTE_USER, but as far as I understand this is intended to be used by CGI or SSI scripts and not for Rewrite or similiar?
2. If it is possible to modify the authenticated user, where would be the place to do so? Is it possible and reasonable to do it in a rewrite block?

Cheers,

Jan

Comment: What methods of authentication and authorization are you using?

Comment: mod_ssl with clientCertificate, the original user name (Joe Smith ABC fhjsdj342) is the CN of the subject of the clientCertificate. Authorization is done by mod_authzn_ldap. However the original user name is not in AD available, but the last token (fhjsdj342). So my plan is to set the Apache user name that is passed to AuthLDAPUrl manually to fhjsdj342.

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem and after a little bit of digging around, i found a solution that worked for me..

I firstly searched about ldap referrals and the options to turn this off in apache..

Turning this off solved the problem for me. it is a directive of the mod_ldap module

LDAPReferrals Off

Comment: I think I still don't have the prerequisites, as I can't identify the AD subject that belongs to the user due to the name mismatch. Actually, my core problem is to map a user identified by a clientCertificate to the AD entry, which is related by the last token (fhjsdj342).